# Getting average from 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, impala

I need help with sql commands~
Thanks for your help in advance ^^

So I have 2 tables

[image: Table information]

How can I get the average from this 2 table.

The result that I want would be

```
Country Code 65 has 49.5 Frequency
Country Code 42 has 17 Frequency
Country Code 33 has 18 Frequency
Country Code 11 has 5 Frequency
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question to include the structure of your tables, some sample data of each, and then the results that you are looking for. If you have any queries that you have tried already, please include them. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further information on enhancing your question.

Comment: Join the tables on country code, then calculate `(table1.frequency+table2.frequency)/2` to get the average.

Comment: What coding attempts have you made?

Comment: There is a [mysql average command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) I would suggest looking at this and if you get stuck come back with a specific problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - this link is very useful, when it comes to asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the two tables as a `UNION ALL` then use that as a sub-query with a `GROUP BY` and an `AVG()` on the `Frequency` column:

```
select cntry_cde, Avg(freq) as freq_avg
from 
(
    select t1.cntry_cde, t1.freq
    from avg_call t1
    union all
    select t2.cntry_cde, t2.freq
    from calls_at_one t2
)
group by cntry_cde;
```